# Receiving "Unable to start the server: Permission denied" when attempting to manually start safaridriver on macOS

Tags: macos, selenium, webdriver, safaridriver

I am attempting to run safardriver from the /usr/bin folder.

If I run the command without sudo, using `/usr/bin/safaridriver -p 0`, I am still prompted for a password. Entering my password or the admins password does not work.

If i run the command `sudo /usr/bin/safaridriver -p 0`, I am prompted for a password, and I enter my password, but recieve the error:

`Unable to start the server: Permission denied`

I have checked the Allow Remote Automation option under the Develop menu in Safari.

Does anyone have any other suggestions on what I might need to do in order to get this to run?

Comment: Using Safari Version 10.0.2 (12602.3.12.0.1)
macOS Sierra Version 10.12.2

Answer (score 0):

The issue was twofold.  I had to restart my machine to get the sudo to work. Once I did that, I also made myself an admin of the machine. This allowed me to run the command without sudo.